# Get entire hierarchy of values in a sql table consisting of two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+------------+
| ChildCode | ParentCode |
+-----------+------------+
| AUSNZ     |   APACZ    |
| EASIAZ    |   APACZ    |
| SEASIAZ   |   APACZ    |
| AUSTR     |   AUSNZ    |
| NZ        |   AUSNZ    |
| PACISZ    |   AUSNZ    |
| TOGO      |   PACISZ   |
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to have all ChildCodes with the ParentCode `APACZ`. However, the problem is that the ChildCode again can be a ParentCode (see `AUSNZ`) - there are multiple layers. Anyone an idea how to get all ChildCodes/ParentCodes belonging to `APACZ`, i.e. to get the entire list of Codes which have `APACZ` as a root?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...and?  Is there any data in that table?

Comment: sorry, had to figure out how to get a table in stackoverflow.

Comment: [This page](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) can make quick work for formatting table data for your question.

Comment: Your question is not clear, a desired outputs will be much more better.

Comment: Look up recursive query. You will find this often for supervisory roles as well as menus.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward recursive CTE.  There are many examples on stackoverflow.  In your case, if you just want the list of children, you could do something like this....

```
;WITH list_structure AS
(
SELECT
    l.Child_Code,
    l.Parent_Code
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME_OF_VALUES_HERE] l
    WHERE l.Parent_Code ='APACZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    l.child_Code,
    l.Parent_Code
    FROM list_hierarchy l
    INNER JOIN list_structure
    ON l.Parent_Code = list_structure.child_Code
)

SELECT Child_Code FROM list_structure
```